# using multiple command for loops in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use multiple line for loops without success - code just seems to bomb out. I've switched on EnableDelayedExpansion but that doesn't seem to help either :-( The code seems to exit after "echo start for loop".

Any ideas why this doesn't work would be much appreciated :-)

Thanks, Helen.

```
:: script to rename tv/radio folders with issue date.

@echo off
:: All vars set in this file will be local:
SETLOCAL
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:SetDate
echo.
set /P NewDate=Please enter date to rename to (yymmdd) or "x" to exit:
echo.
echo new date = %NewDate%
:: Loop to user input until a character is entered:
if "%NewDate%"=="" GOTO Error
If "%NewDate%"=="x" GOTO Exit
:: User has entered a value so confirm it is correct.
GOTO ConfirmDate

:ConfirmDate
echo.
set /P Confirmation=Is this date correct? (y/n):
echo.
echo confirmation = %Confirmation%
if "%Confirmation%"=="y" GOTO RenameFolders
:: Else
GOTO SetDate

:RenameFolders
:: for each folder name containing "xxx", replace "xxx" with the new date
echo.
echo start for loop
for /D %%D in ("?xxx*") do (
    set "PDIR=%%~fD" & set "NAME=%%~nxD"
    echo check whether folder exists
    if EXIST "!NAME:xxx=%NewDate%!" (
        echo.
        echo folders already exist! - remove them and try again!
        GOTO :End
    ) ELSE (
        move "!PDIR!" "!NAME:xxx=%NewDate%!"
    )
)
echo.
echo Folder rename is complete. Thank you.
GOTO End

:Error
echo.
echo You did not enter a date!!
GOTO SetDate

:Exit
echo.
echo User requested exit, bye bye!
GOTO End

:End
::Remember to end command for local vars:
ENDLOCAL
:: exit script
```

Comment: Why not use "pause" to help debug? Anyway, I think there is no error above.

Comment: Thanks, Vancent. However, it definitely doesn't run the for loop code as I never get to the line "echo check whether folder exists" :-( I can only assume it's due to the complexity of the for loop?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do and what does it actually do? the more you tell us the easier it is to help you...

Comment: Ok, what it should do is: the for loop should search for all folders containing the string "xxx" and replace it with a date which was provided by the user earlier in the script. Before trying to use the "move" command for folder rename, the for loop should check whether the new folder name already exists and if it does, exit the script. If it doesn't already exist, the folder(s) should be renamed using the move command. What actually happens: The script falls over somewhere between "echo start for loop" and "echo check whether folder exists"

Comment: My approach would be to remove the entire `if..else` command from the loop and ` echo %%D` as the first line in the `for`. This may reveal which of the statements is causing the problem. I'd also be using a proper text-editor like `editplus` as using a WP can play havoc. Regardless, ensure that the batchfile is being saved as ASCII, not unicode. Sadly, we can't  reproduce your symptoms without a listing of the target directory. The code *appears* to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is nothing really wrong with your for loop when none of the directories exist.

The problem is that when an existing directory is found you have specifically instructed the code to `GOTO :End` which 'breaks' out of the loop.

You will have to decide how best to act in cases of existing directory names and alter your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I never actually get to that point because the code seems to fall over before that point and I can't work out why :-( I'm very new to batch files and associated commands so expect I've possibly made some silly error ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for your help :-)

I have discovered the source of the problem ... somehow the folders containing "xxx" had got deleted from the source/target directory so the for loop had nothing to work with but as echo had been turned off, presumably I missed a message which might have caused me to figure this out sooner! Doh! What a stupid mistake :-( I'll try not to jump the gun so quickly next time ...

Thanks, Helen.